# Unset an entire array in php

Tags: php, arrays

Here my code,
'facilities' is an array.

```
foreach ($prestation['conciergeries'] as $item) {
                    unset(
                        $item->prestation_ids,
                        $item->email,
                        $item->home_title,
                        $item->home_schedule,
                        $item->address,
                        $item->facility_ids,
                        $item['facilities'] <- It doesn't works
                    );
                }
```

Can i delete an entire array with Unset ?

Comment: `unset($item)`? Or even `unset($prestation['conciergeries'])`

Comment: is your `$item` an object? if so, you can't use it as an associative array with `$item['facilities']`. Did you mean `$item->facilities`?

Comment: What do you mean by "table"? There is no such concept as a table in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foreach` is not working like that. You actually `unset` the "mirror array" created in your foreach and you don't affect the real array you are looping.

For your example you could use a `for` loop with a counter instead.

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($prestation['conciergeries']); $i++) {
        unset($prestation['conciergeries'][$i]['facilities']);
    }
```

Comment: If i do a var_dump with your code and i get the table, but the unset doesn't works.

Comment: Did you also try -> facilities?   based on your question you are having an object. maybe your nested array is an object after all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can unset the table `unset($prestation['conciergeries']);` but if you meant empty the table use `$prestation['conciergeries'] = [];`

Answer (score 0):

`$item` in your `foreach` is the right reference to the variable, if it is an object, you can `unset` it's properties and it will reflect in the array, however you cannot unset `$item` directly as it acts like a local variable in the `foreach` loop (`$item` won't exist anymore in the loop after it is unset, but the array entry is not impacted). You can use foreach with the key like this:

```
foreach($prestation['conciergeries'] as $key => $item){
    unset($item->prestation_ids); //will work deleting item property
    unset($prestation['conciergeries'][$key]); //use key instead to unset array entry
}
```

[see it in action here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4e54f0c2f4e0a6a88363d2cf1117cd8bd74f5848)